# How do I know (other than hovering over it) how many people are watching a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching

For an example, if I want to get a list of the 500 most watched tags, it would be impractical to check out the tag popup for each one of them.

Comment: I answered a similar question on MSE here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274622/158100 but checking out the tag popup of each of them is basically what you have to do, although I offer a scraper for you in that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag , watchers info is deliberately missing from StackExchange web API. Likewise, it's missing from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/{tag}/info and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{tag} .

So, you're stuck with a scraper, the site doesn't offer any other way. Either hover things with a headless browser, or find an unsupported way to invoke the same functionality/get this info (which is going to break eventually).